# Is there a config file for ubuntu server like /etc /ethers to config the mac-ip bind?

Tags: ubuntu, arp, configuration

i can't find /etc/ethers in ubuntu server:<
i want save something like "sudo arp -s someipaddress  macaddress" so i don't need to set it again after reboot

Comment: You could create an init.d/ script that would run at boot

Comment: Static ARP entries *bad*... very, **VERY** bad.  Also, just because a file doesn't already exist, doesn't mean the system doesn't recognise it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Ubuntu doesn't ship with `/etc/ethers` but you can certainly create and edit one yourself. (Oddly enough the net-tools package has an *ethers* man page but not the file itself.)